# How to relate to different nodes during CSV import

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///attributes.csv' AS line
MATCH (p:Property {old_id: line.property_id})
MERGE (a:Attribute {description: line.description})-[:ATTRIBUTE_OF {old_id: line.id, value: line.value}]->(p)
```

For each new line, I am trying to merge the Attribute when the description is the same, but make a new relationship to the Property node that has been matched.

The issue I have is that an existing relationship is being replaced with the newer one.

How can I ensure that all previously created relationships are maintained, and only new ones are created?

Comment: Do an OPTIONAL MATCH for the relationship and use WHERE ... IS NOT NULL to check is the relationship does not exist. (Sorry, cannot provide an example as I only have a phone now. )

Comment: I would love to see an example if you have the time (and computer) as I'm pretty new to this. Thanks :)

Comment: I added my answer. Also, I recommend to check out the [Cypher MERGE Explained](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/07/31/cypher-merge-explained.html) post by GraphAware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do it in two steps:

1. First, `MERGE` the attribute when `line.description`is the same.
2. Then, `CREATE` a new relationship between `a` and `p` nodes.

The sample query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///attributes.csv' AS line
MATCH (p:Property {old_id: line.property_id})
MERGE (a:Attribute {description: line.description})
CREATE (a)-[:ATTRIBUTE_OF {old_id: line.id, value: line.value}]->(p)
```

Comment: I didn't realise I could do a merge and create in a single instruction, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///attributes.csv' AS line
MATCH (p:Property {old_id: line.property_id})
OPTIONAL MATCH (:Attribute {description: line.description})-[r:ATTRIBUTE_OF {old_id: line.id, value: line.value}]->(p)
WHERE r IS NULL
CREATE (:Attribute {description: line.description})-[:ATTRIBUTE_OF {old_id: line.id, value: line.value}]->(p)
```

This may behave slightly differently from the query in the solution of Bruno Peres -- please check and report back which worked for your case.

Comment: The other answer worked a treat, but thank you for your input, I know a little more about Cypher now! :D